# full information maximum likelihood for missing data in R combined with a MANOVA

Tags: maximum-likelihood, manova

i would like to do a manova with full information maximum likelihood to reduce missing data.

i dont find any help in the internet, just how to calculate a normal manova, but if i add the usual command missing = 'fiml' it doesnt work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding the best package for implementing FIML for missing data within a MANOVA is Lavaan ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/lavaan.pdf ) - page 20 provides the example syntax for an anova. This [online lecture](https://jonathantemplin.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/mv18epsy905_MultivariateLinearModelsIntro.pdf) may also be helpful, specifically starting around slide 14.

Using FIML does come with some assumptions, too - this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3701793/#Sec17title) may be helpful for learning more about those and understanding if FIML is right for your data.

good luck!